# Show that there is a surjective homomorphism from $\pi_1(K,x_0)$ onto $D_6$

Tags: algebraic-topology

(a) Show that there is a surjective homomorphism from $\pi_1(K,x_0)$ onto $D_6$, where $K$ is the klein bottle and $D_6$ is the dihedral group of order $6$.\
(b) Prove that there is no covering map from $K$ to a torus.

Thanks a lot! I have no idea at all.

Comment: First of all, do you know how to compute $\pi_1(K, x_0)$?

Comment: <a,b|aba^{-1}b>?

Comment: Well, $D_6 = \langle a, b | aba^{-1} b = a^3 = b^2 = 1 \rangle$, so it should to possible to find a surjective homomorphism from $\pi_1(K, x_0)$ onto $D_6$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) A typical presentation of $\pi_1(K)$ is $\langle a,b \mid abab^{-1} = 1\rangle$ One particularly useful presentation of the dihedral group $D_6$ is $\langle x,y \mid x^6 = y^2 = xyxy^{-1} =1\rangle$. Then we can define a $f:\pi_1(K) \rightarrow D_6$ by $f(a)=x,f(b)=y$ and easily check that $f$ is a surjective homomorphism.

b) We proceed by contradiction. Assume $p:K \rightarrow T$ where $T$ is the torus, is a covering space. It is a fundamental result that the induced map $p_*:\pi_1(K)\rightarrow \pi_1(T)$ is injective. Thus for the presentation 
$$\pi_1(K) \approx \langle a,b \mid abab^{-1} = 1\rangle$$ 
As $p_*$ is a homomorphism and $\pi_1(T) $ is abelian

$$p_*(abab^{-1}) = p_*(a)p_*(b)p_*(a)p_*(b)^{-1} = p_*(a)^2 = 1$$

As $\pi_1(T) \approx \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ has no element of order $2$ we conclude that $p_*(a) =1$ which is a contradiction as $ a \neq 1$ in $\pi_1(K)$. Thus $p:K \rightarrow T$ is not a covering space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question. Do we really need that $p_*$ is injective since $a\neq 1$ as a generator of a group already.